# Execute php after 10s non blocking

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk

Building a Facebook application and due to Facebook rules i must wait 10 seconds before executing a posting of user action.

This can be done with JavaScript also but have found the php sdk more precise.

My question is, What is the best and most accurate way of delaying the execution of code 10s

```
$response = $facebook->api(
'me/video.watches',
'POST',
array(
'tv_show' => "$permalink"
)
);
```

Using sleep(10); will block the entire page from loading. What is the correct solution here ?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by creating a database table and feed your database with records to be sent as post.
Create a cron at your server that reads the unprocessed records and create a facebook post to desired user.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is some form of asynchrones processing. There are a number of different approaches you could take.

- Write 'jobs' to a file, table in database, etc. and have a cronjob handle them.
- Fork your PHP process, serving the response to the user in the 'parent' process and posting to Facebook in the 'child' proces.
- Start a new process and detach it. (`exec('php postToFacebook.php > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &');`)
- Use a job server system such as [Gearman](http://gearman.org/).

  I'd rate Gearman the coolest, the 'new process and detach' trick is probably the easiest.

Comment: Have been experimented with "Start a new process and detach it" but can't get it to work, Can you give me an example how it could look like ?

Comment: @MathiasÅsberg Can you replace the & with `> /dev/null 2>/dev/null &` and see if that does work for you?

Comment: Have been trying everything it seems but i can't get it to work, This would be correct 
exec('php myAction.php > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &');

Comment: I've tested this, but it only appears to work when calling a script commandline. Another option it to use `at`, in something using `exec("echo 'php child.php'|at now");`. Let me know if it works so I can update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Using sleep(10); will block the entire page from loading. What is the correct solution here ?

shot in the dark, try rendering the page first then calling the sleep()? it's difficult to advise a "simple" solution without context on how you are handling the response and what sort of stuff the user needs to see rendered.

Answer (score 0):

You could trigger the Facebook operation via an AJAX call from the client side. You could use a simple `setTimeout()` to delay the call once the page has loaded:

```
setTimeout( function(){
  // Execute your AJAX call
}, 10000 ); // 1000 miliseconds = 1 second
```

The page that is being called via AJAX can simply execute the request to Facebook as usual.